# Interdisciplinary Calculus and Statistics Texts for Advanced Secondary Students

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, interdisciplinary

I'm planning some interdisciplinary options for future students at a small independent school to be implemented in the next few years. The courses would be offered as independent studies and students would consult with faculty in both departments.

Unfortunately I've come up short in finding calculus and statistics texts that contain enough of the cross-disciplinary material but are appropriate for advanced high-schoolers. I came across a text called "Calculus for Biology and Medicine", which is an example (at least in theory- I haven't gotten my hands on a copy) of the type of text I'm looking for. Other disciplines I would like to be available to students are economics & calculus, engineering & calculus, social sciences & statistics, ecological science & statistics.

The ideal text would not simply teach calculus or statistics with exercises in the cross discipline, but utilize principles in both disciplines to teach topics in both. Introductory undergraduate texts in these disciplines are alright as long as they contain enough material approachable to advanced high school students to fill a year-long course.

(1) What sorts of programs like this have been successfully implemented in the past?

(2) What books should serve as texts four courses like these?

Comment: In US colleges the calculus version of such a course is typically called applied calculus.  Textbooks by that name usually have problems taken from a variety of discipline.  E.g., the Hughes-Hallet book with that name.  I imagine most stats books by their nature have applications from a variety of fields.

Comment: @ncr Indeed. I'm looking for texts that teach ordinary curriculum topics from differential and integral calculus or statistics, perhaps all three, while applying them to obtain results in just one or a few related fields like economics and business or biology and ecology. I have seen some texts for post-secondary courses that do this, though they assume some-post secondary prerequisites.

Comment: So you mean a book more like Stewart and Day's Biocalculus?  The Table of Contents can be found online.  The high school I taught at used Stewart in its Calculus classes.

Comment: Statistics includes a hefty dollop of combinatorics too. This sounds like a *very* demanding course....

Comment: @ncr If you say so- my aim with the question is to see if anyone else has used books like those. We have a hand full of students who have already passed both AP calculus courses- occasionally we have sophomores that complete both. I'm exploring options for these few students.

Comment: @vonbrand Of course. It would probably be taken by just a handful of students each year.